# Returning function pointer type

Tags: c, syntax, types, function-pointers

Often I find the need to write functions which return function pointers. Whenever I do, the basic format I use is:

```
typedef int (*function_type)(int,int);

function_type getFunc()
{
   function_type test;
   test /* = ...*/;
   return test;
}
```

However this can get cumbersome when dealing with a large number of functions so I would like to not have to declare a typedef for each one (or for each class of functions)

I can remove the typedef and declare the local variable returned in the function as:
`int (*test)(int a, int b);` making the function body look like this:

```
{
     int (*test)(int a, int b);
     test /* = ...*/;
     return test;
}
```

but then I do not know what to set for the return type of the function.
I have tried:

```
int(*)(int,int) getFunc()
{
    int (*test)(int a, int b);
    test /* = ...*/;
    return test;
}
```

but that reports a syntax error. How do I declare the return type for such a function without declaring a typedef for the function pointer. Is it even possible? Also note that I am aware that it seems like it would be cleaner to declare typedefs, for each of the functions, however, I am very careful to structure my code to be as clean and easy to follow as possible. The reason I would like to eliminate the typedefs is that they are often only used to declare the retrieval functions and therefore seem redundant in the code.

Comment: +1, interesting, I was wondering that myself a while ago, and just used a typedef .

Comment: Shouldn't `test_type` be `function_type`? (Not that it matters that much, but just to be completely clear.)

Comment: You're missing some stuff in your question (e.g. what's the definition of `test_type`).  Makes answering your question much more difficult when we're confused. lol

Comment: yeah that was a typo it should have been function_type

Comment: You mean like enumerating all of the function prototypes in a union and setting the return type to the union identifier?

Comment: @SE Yes.  I'm trying to come up with a good example to post as an answer, unless you think that's not the way to go...

Comment: well it is a creative alternative to avoid using the typedefs, but if I have to enumerate all of the prototypes in the union it seems like i might as well just do the typedefs. but +1 for the alternative idea

Comment: @EricPostpischil has the correct answer, but personally I'd go with the typedefs: they are not redundant because they have a purpose, which is to make the code readable.

Comment: @SE What situation/case makes you need to call function that returning function pointer rather than just calling function itself?

Comment: @AndyLin There are many. Pretty much any time you have to write a library wrapper. Just to pick a real world example off the top of my head, suppose you are writing an opengl application and want to support dynamically loading whatever version of opengl is on the user's system. Then you write a wrapper around open gl and load each gl function that you use from the library dynamically. In such cases upon initialization you want to return each gl function by looking up its name in that version of open gl. In fact open gl has extensions that are intended to load that way

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
int (*getFunc())(int, int) { … }
```

That provides the declaration you requested. Additionally, as [ola1olsson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/317451/ola1olsson) notes, it would be good to insert `void`:

```
int (*getFunc(void))(int, int) { … }
```

This says that `getFunc` may not take any parameters, which can help avoid errors such as somebody inadvertently writing `getFunc(x, y)` instead of `getFunc()(x, y)`.

Comment: I have a class member function and I want it to return a function pointer. How can I do it ? I can't find how . I tried this way you say above but it didn't work.

Comment: Good answer. But totally braindead C function pointer syntax.

Comment: I would suggest to add the "void" keyword between the empty parenthesis so the compiler can catch the mistake where the caller of getFunc() might think that he/she gives the int,int argument to the real function and not to getFunc(). I.e. you want the compiler to catch "getFunc(x,y)" since the caller probably wants to do "getFunc()(x,y)".

Comment: Might be off topic, but, its easy to evaluate complex function declaration using [Clockwise/Spiral Rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

Comment: On second thought, I think I'll just deal with the tedium/indirection of type-aliasing the function pointer type

Answer (score 7):

You can probably do something like:

```
int foo (char i) {return i*2;}

int (*return_foo()) (char c)
{
   return foo;
}
```

but god, I hope I'll never have to debug you code....

Comment: as I said in the problem, I wouldnt use it in a scenario where it made the code messy. It is only for those rare occasions when declaring a lot of the typedefs is redundant

Answer (score 4):

ill leave this here since it was a bit trickier than answers already given, as it takes a function pointer

> `(int (__cdecl *)(const char *))`

and returns a function pointer

> `(int (__cdecl *)(const char *))`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int (*idputs(int (*puts)(const char *)))(const char *) {
    return puts;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    idputs(puts)("Hey!");

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While wrapping some C code in C++ classes, I had the same desire as the original poster: return a function pointer from a function without resorting to `typedef`'ing the function pointer prototype. I hit a problem with C++ `const` correctness which I thought was worth sharing, even if it's a little off-topic (C++) but it does relate directly to the original question: the syntax for returning a C function pointer without resorting to a `typedef`.

The code below defines a class `A` which stores a function pointer and exposes it to the outside world through the `get_f()` call. This is the function that should return a function pointer without a `typedef`.

The point (which stumped me for some time) was how to declare that `get_f()` was a `const` function, i.e. it wouldn't alter `A`.

The code contains 2 variants: the first uses a typedef for the function pointer prototype, whilst the second writes everything out in full. The `#if` switches between the two.

```
#include <iostream>

int my_f(int i)
{
  return i + 1;
}

#if 0 // The version using a typedef'ed function pointer

typedef int (*func_t)(int);

class A
{
public:
  A(func_t f) : m_f(f) {}
  func_t get_f() const { return m_f; }

private:
  func_t m_f;
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const A a(my_f);
  std::cout << "result = " << a.get_f()(2) << std::endl;
}

#else // The version using explicitly prototyped function pointer    

class A
{
public:
  A(int (*f)(int)) : m_f(f) {}
  int (*get_f() const)(int) { return m_f; }

private:
  int (*m_f)(int);
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const A a(my_f);
  std::cout << "result = " << a.get_f()(2) << std::endl;
}

#endif
```

The expected/desired output is:

```
result = 3
```

The key point is the position of the `const` qualifier in the line:

```
int (*get_f() const)(int) { return m_f; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got three options:

1. Stick with typedef. At the end of the day, it's typedef's job.
2. Return void* and the casting it.
3. Reconsider your software architecture. Perhaps you could share with us what you're trying to achieve and see if we can point you toward a better direction.

Comment: Note that a `void *` is not (necessarily) compatible with a function-pointer.

Comment: A pointer to void is a pointer to an object type, and the C standard does not define the behavior of casting pointers to object types to pointers to function types or vice-versa. You can convert a pointer to a function type to a pointer to another function type, as long as you cast it to a compatible type before using it.

Comment: I'm not trying to achieve anything specifically at the moment its just a problem I have occasionally run into when doing things such as dynamically linking to shared libraries across multiple versions using libld

Answer (score 0):

This is a stupid example, but it's simple and it does not give errors. It's just about declaring static functions:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void * asdf(int);
static int * hjkl(char,float);

main() {
  int a = 0;
  asdf(a);
 }


void * asdf(int a) {return (void *)hjkl; }
static int * hjkl(char a, float b) {int * c; return c;}
```

Comment: The C standard does not define the behavior of casting pointers-to-data to pointers-to-function.  Also, this is not simpler than the OP's example.

Comment: actually he is not casting a pointer to data to a pointer to a function. He has a pointer to a function, and he is casting to a void* and then casting it back to a function. this is valid, and in fact void* return types is how GNU's dlsym function works, the problem is, that it is basically a form of weak-typing which I try to avoid

Answer (score 0):

You can write the following code(It only works in C++11 and above):

```
//C++11
auto func(...) {
    int (*fptr)(...) ret = ...
    //Do sth.
    return ret;//C++11 compiler will automatically deduce the return type for you
}
```

Or, if you do not like automatic return type deduction, you can specified the type at the end of the function(Same as above, only in C++11 and above):

```
//C++11
auto func(...) -> int (*)(...) { /* Do sth. */ }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but the question was about c not c++.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example fun function which take void as argument which returns function pointer that function should take int* and int* and returns int*

check the link example using typedef
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/returning-a-function-pointer-from-a-function-in-c-cpp/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int* fun1(int* y, int* z)
{
    static int var = 0;
    var = (*y + *z);
    printf("Inside fun1 = %d\n", var );
    return &var;
}

int* (*fun())(int*,int*)
{
    printf("Inside fun\n");
    return &fun1;
}

int main()
{
    int a=10,b=20;
    int *ptr = NULL;
    int* (*(*fp)())(int*,int*) = &fun;
    ptr=(*fp())(&a,&b);
    printf("*ptr = %d\n", *ptr );
}
```