# Possible return types for a C function

Tags: c, function, return-value

What are the possible data types in C
apart from void, int, float, char, double, long and struct?

I am writing a regex(script) to detect the starting of the function body.
I need the return types so that I can get the function body starting by concatenating the return type with the function name.

Comment: FYI: using regex to parse C probably won't work. Determining the difference between a variable name and a type name is sometimes dependent on which types have been defined, IIRC.

Comment: @Mat i was thinking to match the function prototype thereby getting to the start of the function by matching 
"return-type function name with parenthesis" like
int fun_name()

Comment: @user4377237: I hadn't understood that you're actually _parsing_ C. regex doesn't sound like the right tool. Consider [this sort of declaration](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20617529/635608).

Comment: @Mat : true, i have to find an alternate solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/526797/good-tools-for-creating-a-c-c-parser-analyzer, @user4377237

Comment: You could've the searched the web first :)

Answer (score 3):

A C function can return any of the following:

- integral datatype (_Bool<sup>C99</sup>/char/short/int/long/long long and signed/unsigned variants)
- floating-point datatype (float/double/long double [and _Complex variants]<sup>C99</sup>)
- structure and union values (values of type `struct ...` or `union ...`)
- enumeration values (values of type `enum ...`)
- pointers to any of the above (and pointers to any pointer)
- function pointers
- void

with optional const and/or volatile qualification at any level. Typedef names for any such type are of course also allowed.

Notably, a C function cannot return a value of function type, nor may it return a value of array type (though it can return function pointers and structures containing arrays, respectively).

Comment: @chux: Thanks, I added _Bool and _Complex from C99. The C99 spec allows pointers to _Bool (and IIRC sizeof(_Bool) must be 1, so it cannot be a single bit unless it is a bitfield structure element).

Comment: Note: although not needed for this answer, per your comment, maybe `sizeof(_Bool)` must be at _least_ 1: "number of bits in a _Bool object is at least CHAR_BIT," C11 §6.7.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Any (complete) object type or `void`, except arrays types, can be returned by a function. Through the `struct` and `enum` keywords, new types can be created by the programmer so there are potentially an infinite number of types functions can return in C.

Comment: Any type? Not any type. Certainly not function types, but also not arrays.

Comment: `void` is also a possible return type.

Answer (score 1):

Except arrays, a function can return values of any type.

Arrays can be returned if inside a struct.

```
struct innerarray {
    double values[100];
};

struct innerarray fx(void) {
    struct innerarray retval;
    for (int k = 0; k < 100; k++) retval.values[k] = k;
    return retval;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A function can return either `void` or a complete, non-array, object type, including user-defined types.

Specifically, the following are forbidden:

```
typedef int f();     // function type
typedef int a[10];   // array type
struct X;            // incomplete, non-array object type

// f foo1();         // Error, function returning function
// a foo2();         // Error, function returning array

// struct X foo3(){} // Error, attempting to define function with incomplete
                     // return type

struct X foo4();     // OK, can *declare* a function with incomplete return type
```

Comment: Amusingly, C does have the syntax (in theory) for defining a function that returns both function and array type: `void foo1(void)(void);` returns a `void (void)` function, and `int foo1(void)[10];` returns an array. (Neither will compile, but your compiler will correctly infer the return type and then ban it)

Comment: @nneonneo: Yes, I'm aware of that, but I figured that would seriously obscure the presentation :-)