# How do you write a function pointer that returns a function pointer without using typedefs?

Tags: c, return, function-pointers

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617067/returning-function-pointer-type), but it never specified how to declare a function pointer that returns a pointer-to-a-function (it simply defined how to create a function returning a function pointer).

While it would probably be wiser to use typedefs, I am interested in the syntax to accomplish this without typedefs.

This is the closest I got:

```
struct function_hash_table {
  unsigned int(*(*getFunction)(Type, Type, Type))( char *name );
}
```

(What type actually is is rather irrelevant to this question).

But, when I try to call it like this:

```
hash_table.getFunction( "Test" );
```

I get errors for too few parameters and wrong parameter types.

**To Clarify:**

```
unsigned int(*hash_get_function(Type, Type, Type))(char *name)
```

Works good for actual functions and explained in the link. However, how am I suppose to declare a function pointer that refers to such a definition?

Comment: "it never specified how to declare a function pointer that returns a function (it simply defined how to create a function returning a function pointer)" – in C, function designators are not first-class. You can't return a function. You can only return a function pointer.

Comment: My wording is apparently misleading. I understand what you just said, but that wasn't what I was asking about. If I didn't have to put getFunction inside a struct, then I would be able to write it correctly. The question is how to define a function pointer that is equivalent to a function that isnt inside the structure.

Comment: it doesn't matter whether your pointer is a member of a struct or a "stand-alone" variable. The declaration is the same.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant And the point totally whooshed past your head... Actually, I got the syntax correct but read the declaration improperly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how to declare a function pointer that returns a pointer-to-a-function

Without using `typedef` you can declare as

```
Type (* (*funcPtr)(Type, Type) ) (Type);
```

Declaration read as: *`funcPtr` is a pointer to a function that expects two arguments of type `Type` and returns a pointer to a function that expects an argument of type `Type` and returns `Type`*.

If you wan to declare a function that return a pointer then

```
Type (* func(Type, Type) ) (Type);
```

Declaration read as: *`func` is a function that accepts two parameters of type `Type` and returns a pointer to function that accepts an argument of type `Type` and returns `Type`*.

Now you can assign `func` to `funcPtr`

```
functPtr = func;
```

Comment: I think I see now. I need to reverse the oparameter locations.