# Why is constructor being elided for this unnamed temporary with side effects with normal initialization but not with braced list initialization?

Tags: c++11, constructor, temporary, c++98

I wanted to test whether a temporary object would live at least as long as the temporary object that held a const reference to it, so I came up with this example.

```c++
#include <iostream>

struct Test {
    Test() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    ~Test() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Holder {
    Holder(const Test& t):m_t(t) {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }
    ~Holder() {
        std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    const Test& m_t;
};

int main() {
    Holder(Test());

    return 0;
}
```

However, I was quite surprised to see that **the compiler had actually optimized out the whole thing**, as can be seen on [codebolt](https://godbolt.org/g/2FN9Qi)

But, if I actually give a *name* to the temporary, by changing the line

```
Holder(Test());
```

into

```
Holder h((Test()));
```

Then it "magically" works: [codebolt](https://godbolt.org/g/KvCKSM).

**Plot twist**: if I switch to c++11 and use the braced list initialization for the `Holder` class, then the constructor is not elided no matter whether I give a name to the temporary or not. See [codebolt](https://godbolt.org/g/jzRH0I) again.

So what's the matter here? I was under the impression that constructors with side effects would never be elided, but I'm obviously missing an important piece of the standard that changed between versions.

Can anybody give me a hint?

Comment: `Holder(Test());` is a variant of most vexing parse.

Comment: Oh darn! To think that I took into account the most vexing parse in the very example I've given, with the named variable.

Comment: It's the extra pair of parentheses that inhibits the most vexing parse. `Holder h(Test());` is the most vexing parse, `Holder h((Test()));` is not.

Comment: Yes, @Oktalist, that's what I meant, but I can't use the extra pair of parentheses in the unnamed case, that would be a syntax error. It's interesting this is declared a _variant_ of the most vexing parse, because so far I had always seen it in the case solved by the extra pair of parentheses.

Comment: It's not a syntax error, but interestingly `Holder((Test()))` is still the most vexing parse.

Comment: Yes, you are right, sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [most vexing parse issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse): `Holder(Test());` declares a function named `Test` that returns `Holder` and accepts 0 arguments.

With g++ the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct Test {};
struct Holder { Holder(Test); };

template<class T>
char const* f() { return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__; }

int main() {
    Holder(Test());
    std::cout << f<decltype(&Test)>() << '\n';
}
```

Outputs:

```
const char* f() [with T = Holder (*)()]
```

An easy fix is to use C++11 braces for initialization: `Holder(Test{});` or `Holder{Test{}};`.

Comment: Ok, ahah, this really got me. I've never seen a function declared that way, I would never imagine it could be a function declaration. Is this an unwanted side effect of the grammar, or does it actually have uses?

Comment: @skypjack There is no such thing as _forward declaration_ in the C++ standard. See _§3.1 Declarations and definitions_.

Comment: @FabioA *"or does it actually have uses?"* By *it*, do you refer to allowing parentheses around function name and argument list? You need it at least for declaring a function that returns a function pointer.

Comment: @skypjack We agree to disagree agreeably. The gist of your messages was that _forward declaration_ was a thing different from _declaration_.

Comment: @user2079303, You mean like in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20617529/566849). But if I remove the asterisk from that line the compiler complains with a syntax error.

Comment: Ok, so if it's not a _a function named Test that returns Holder_, what is it?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin, if I use `Holder(Test)()`, i.e. if I take out the inner paretheses, it still compiles and gives the same result: [ideone](http://ideone.com/1TOzY0). This syntax is way more familiar to me, and totally less ambiguous. So do you know why it's allowed to use the other one too?

Comment: @skypjack, then why `is_same` returns true in both cases?

Comment: @FabioA. See how declarations are parsed: http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html

Comment: Sorry guys, I had linked the wrong ideone. It was meant to be this one: http://ideone.com/1TOzY0