# Return a function pointer from a class member function

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the class AbstractOdeSolver which is the following :

```
class AbstractOdeSolver
{
private:
    double (*rightHandSide)(double y,double t);

public:
    AbstractOdeSolver(int nop,double initime, double fintime, double initval, double(*pf)(double,double));
    double (*GetRightHandSide)(double y, double t)();
};
```

So I have a class with a private member a function pointer namely rightHandSide and  I want to return it from a member function. So ...

1. I don't know if the last line of the code define what I want to define, but I write having in thought this answer [Returning function pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617067/returning-function-pointer-type).
2. If the last line is right then I want to know how can I write the implementation in the `AbstractOdeSolver.cpp`? I tried:

   ```
   double (*AbstractOdeSolver::GetRightHandSide)(double y, double t)()
   ```

   but this is not accepted even from the editor(Kdevelop) and I think with a small revision it is referred to something-like pointer to a member function not to a pointer to a function.

Note that I want to return a pointer to a function which take two doubles and 
returns a double, if it cannot be done it is ok.

Comment: I do know that these two things are not the same thing but I see the link I have pasted and I think it can be done what I am thinking. Also I don't want to use std::function I want something more simple if it's possible.
Thank you @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question a little. But *why* don't you want to use `std::function`? With `std::function` you're not limited to non-member functions or non-capturing lambdas. With `std::function` you have an object that can be treated like just about any other object (like e.g. `std:vector` or `std::string`), and that you can easily return or otherwise copy.

Comment: *"but this is not accepted"*. Show the error message.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I want to solve it without existing classes, if I can't find the solution like the answer at the link I pasted at my question, I will instantly use the std::function because I have read about this. 
Thank you again.

Comment: @Jarod42 at the editor the function was in red color and write something about  the '{'.

Comment: Unless you are using a very simplified compiler, or have very special requirements that forbid you, you will always have access to the standard library. It will always be there for you. Use it! It will make your life as a C++ programmer *so* much easier. Or as the saying goes, don't reinvent the wheel. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC what do you want, the most simple way is use `typedef`:

```
class AbstractOdeSolver 
{
public:
    typedef double (*FSolver)(double, double);
    ....
    FSolver GetRightHandSide();
};
....
AbstractOdeSolver::FSolver AbstractOdeSolver::GetRightHandSide()
{ 
    // just for an example:
    return +[](double, double) -> double { return 0.0; }    
}
```

The same without `typedef`:

```
class AbstractOdeSolver
{
public:
    double (* GetRightHandSide())(double, double);
};

double (*AbstractOdeSolver::GetRightHandSide())(double, double)
{
    return +[](double, double) -> double {return 0.0; };
}
```

And with trailing return type as suggested by @Jarod42:

```
class AbstractOdeSolver
{
public:
    auto GetRightHandSide() -> double (*)(double, double);
};

auto AbstractOdeSolver::GetRightHandSide() -> double (*)(double, double)
{
    return +[](double, double) -> double {return 0.0; };
}
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to do it without the typedef ... something similar to the link I pasted to my question above?

Comment: Trailing return type help: `auto AbstractOdeSolver::GetRightHandSide() -> double (*)(double, double)`.

Comment: @user2807083 If you know It will so kind of you to tell me this unreadable solution.