# I get a warning about incompatible return type

Tags: c, pointers

I have the following code:

```
static void dmaCallbackHandler(tSOME_ENUM channel)
{
    switch(channel)
    {
        case blabla:
              //do some stuff

    }
    func();
}
```

and then some lines below I have a function that returns the address of the function above, and I call this function (_test_getDmaCallbackHandler) from another .c file:

```
uint32* _test_getDmaCallbackHandler(void)
{
    return &dmaCallbackHandler;
}
```

And I'm getting a warning that says the following:

```
warning: returning 'void (*)(tSOME_ENUM)' {aka 'void (*)(enum <anonymous>)'}
         from a function with incompatible return type 'uint32 *' 
         {aka 'unsigned int *'}
         [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

472 |     return &dmaCallbackHandler;
```

**How do I get rid of this warning?**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? `&dmaCallbackHandler` is a function pointer, it has nothing to do with a `uint32*`

Comment: I need access to the function dmaCallbackHandler from another module that tests this file.

Comment: I know that &dmaCallbackHandler is a function pointer, that's exactly what I want

Comment: But you cannot access a function pointer via a `uint32*` - so that return type makes no sense here. As the warning states you should be returning the actual function pointer type (`void(*)(tSOME_ENUM)`)

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. How do I do that exactly?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning function pointer type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20617067/returning-function-pointer-type)

Comment: Well, not really but almost. Didn't work still getting a warning.

Comment: What's the reason for not just exporting the function and calling it when needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What the compiler says: you specified the return type as `uint32_t*` then pass it a completely unrelated type in the form of a function pointer, which is not in the slightest compatible.

So it appears that your code should be changed to this:

```
typedef void dma_callback_t (tSOME_ENUM channel);
...

dma_callback_t* _test_getDmaCallbackHandler(void)
{
    return dmaCallbackHandler;
}
```

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you. But if I don't want to use a typedef, how to implement it then?

Comment: @Bei The non-typedef version isn't recommended since it relies on C's braindead function pointer syntax: `void (*_test_getDmaCallbackHandler(void))(tSOME_ENUM channel)
{ return dmaCallbackHandler; }` aka unreadable crap code.

Comment: hehe yes I finally got it right without typedef, but then I got some other warnings when I assigned the address to a pointer variable of the typ uint32* like this:
uint32* dmaHandlerAddress = _test_getDmaCallbackhandler()

It complained about conflicting types, so it turned out to be the best solution with the typedef, then I could just use the following:

dma_callback_t* dmaHandlerAddress = _test_getDmaCallbackHandler();

Comment: @Bei Uh-huh. Always use typedef when using function pointers.